# Translate SQL query to mongoDB containing joins and a nested table

Tags: mysql, sql, mongodb

I'm completely new to mongoDB, and wondering if it's even possible to query something like this in the mongo language:

```
SELECT 
stg.emp_user_id as emp_user_id,
stg.mgr_user_id as mgr_user_id,
stg.emp_email as emp_email,
stg.employeetype as employeetype,
s.shift_start_time as  shift_start_time,
s.shift_end_time as  shift_end_time,
s.days_worked as days_worked,
s.num_employees as num_employees,
FROM(
#nested table to link the employee to the manager, based on employee email
SELECT
u.userid as emp_user_id,
p.userid as mgr_user_id,
u.email as emp_email,
u.employeetype as employeetype,
FROM Users u
LEFT JOIN Peoples p on u.email = p.email) stg
#bring in shifts table linked to mgr, now that we have mgr-emp relationship
LEFT JOIN shifts s ON stg.mgr_user_id = s.user_id;
```

I've been looking around and have been able to find simple conversion references (querymongo.com, stackoverflow examples, etc), but haven't found anything for joins and nested tables. Any help/direction would be appreciated!

Comment: You can't since `mongodb` don't have any concept called `joins`. rather have something called `embedded documents`

Comment: you can. just google $lookup mongodb.

Comment: @Rahul starting from MongoDB 3.2 you can left join two collections.